# PHP check url and if cookie is set, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to use a snippet in wordpress (using a snippet plugin) to check the current url, if correct, then check if a particular cookie is set. If the cookie isn't set, redirect to previous url. No matter what I've tried, it's like it skips checking if the cookie set and continues to redirect regardless.

```
function get_current_url()
{
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {
        $pageURL .= "s";
    }
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "۸۰") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }

    return $pageURL;
}

$url = get_current_url();
$no_c_redirect = 'https://example.com/content/file.html';

if (strpos($url, '/secured-registration/') !== false) {
    if (isset($_COOKIE["thename"]) && $_COOKIE["_r_ck"] == "thevalue") {
    } else {
        header('Location: '.$no_c_redirect);
    }
}
```

Comment: For every `if` there's a potential `else`. When you are debugging things like this, put something that _screams_ to you in those conditions such as https://3v4l.org/8tEtk. Also, `SERVER_PORT` will either be an int or possibly a numeric string, however your test, `"۸۰"`, feels sort of like an attempt at RegEx. Instead you just want `isset($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"])`

Answer (score -1):

I have discovered the root of the problem to be a caching issue, not a code issue. I’ve managed to use page caching rules to solve this and it’s now working as it should.